# Usable ram is half of total memory

Tags: ram

Recently i had added a 2GB DDR3 ram in my acer laptop. As a result my total ram is 4GB (2x2). I was running ubuntu 12.04 32bit(pae kernel). Everything was working fine. Now i have upgraded (new install) to 13.04 64bit. Suddenly i noticed that system is showing only 1.7GB. So i run **`lshw`** to ensure the fact. But **lshw** shows correct result (4GB = 2x2). How could i solve this??? There is no settings in **BIOS** for ram at all. My system is newly installed. No additional applications is installed except amd-catalyst driver.

System:

```
Acer aspire 4250 E-450 apu
```

[image]

[image]

**Note: BISO also showing that 4GB ram installed.**

Comment: I have the same problem. Even windows shows 4Gb Installed and only 1.74 usable. Did you fixed it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved my problem by cleaning the ram modules. But i don't understand that why lshw was showing 4gb ram.

Answer (score 0):

that is very strange.  This question has some suggestions.[RAM upgrade installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98637/ram-upgrade-installation) which may be worth looking at. It looks like Ubuntu only reports the ram which isn't given out to hardware e.g graphics cards.http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1452306

Comment: thanks for quick reply. First link doesn't sense for this issue. I had already mentioned that i am using 64bit system. Second issue is doubtable. But i checked. I have un-installed graphics driver but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a stab at this.  Since you have an APU, I would go into the BIOS, and make sure that the video card is not using the missing RAM.

To find out how much ram the video card is using,  just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo dmesg | grep drm
```

or you can install System Info

```
sudo apt-get install sysinfo
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. sysinfo is showing 1.7GB ram, and here is the output of dmesg. http://pastebin.com/vzxcZ2GT  VRAM is showing 256MB in BIOS

Comment: Can tell me more info about the RAM that you added? manufacturer, and model number?

Comment: transcend ram (2GB, 1330MHZ). I had already used it for 1 month in ubuntu 12.04. But notice this problem once in ubuntu 13.04 (64bit). Sorry i don't know the model number.

Comment: Try removing it, clean the contacts with an eraser, and put it back in.  Make sure that it click good in place.