# Ubuntu 20.04 says my computer has 4 GB RAM total instead of 8 GB RAM

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive, hardware, ram

I was noticing my performance on Ubuntu was a little slow after running some codes, and I decided to research on how to upgrade my laptop. I ran into the free -m command, and I was shocked to find out that, despite my RAM board being 8 Gb, it only displays as if I had 4 Gb.

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3845        1870         259         254        1715        1477
Swap:         15258           9       15249
```

Afterwards, I confirmed the state of my memory going to `Settings > About`, where I find this:

[image: [Screenshot from my Ubuntu's About page]]

I don't understand much on hardware and on Ubuntu in general, as I only recently transformed my Windows 10 into a Ubuntu dual-boot, then finally taking the plunge to have Ubuntu as my only boot. Did I screw something up? Do I have to format everything and start again? How do I make my computer use its 8 GB Ram?

As additional information: my laptop is a Samsung Expert L40, NP350XAA-XD1BR.

EDIT: I double checked my RAM and it's a 4 GB - seems there's an onboard 4GB memory I don't have access to, visually. But Samsung BIOS confirm it's 8 GB:

[image: Photo of BIOS]

EDIT 2: SOLVED! Just needed to clear RAM with a cotton swab. Turns out it was hardware related.

Comment: This answer of another question might help you;

[usable ram is half of total memory][1]


  [1]: https://askubuntu.com/questions/315110/usable-ram-is-half-of-total-memory

Comment: You're right - I just cleaned my RAM with a cotton swab. It's back! Thanks!

Comment: No problem. I'm glad it worked